# Restore old Cordova LocalStorage data in Ionic6 and Capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, capacitor

The Question is simple, i have a Old App im working on Implementig. For the new version i use Ionic 6 and Capacitor. The old app used Cordova/Phonegap with `window.localStorage`.

I tried a few different approaches to solve the problem with my own take at it.
I created a Plugin for Angular that tries to access the localStorage location but with no success.
Either im unable to find the right filepath an the filename, or im not using the right database.
My take was SQLite3 to access the localStorage.

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-capacitor-localstorage-missing/187519
- https://github.com/wootwoot1234/react-native-webkit-localstorage-reader

Comment: Hello, I would like to know if you have found a solution for this, I am also facing this problem.

Comment: I wrote a complete Plugin since i didnt find anything: 
https://github.com/Lucas-Feichtinger/migrate-cordova-localstorage

Comment: This sounds good but it seems that this repo is private because I can not see it in your profile (I just can see 4 repositories: UiCallAnnotation, compressjs, cached-images, and translation-module)

Comment: Oh i did not notice that, changed it to public you should be able to view it now

Answer (score 1):

try to add the following configurations to the capacitor.config file:

```
  server: {
    iosScheme: 'ionic',
    androidScheme: 'https'
  }
```

Comment: are you refering to the question or the repository?

Comment: I am referring to the question, I faced this issue recently and I fixed it like that. My configuration is ionic 5 and capacitor 3, but it should work also with ionic 6.

Comment: So your telling me that i programmed this complex plugin for no reason :(